# Lambda Function Won't Take Argument

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function built in node.js. I have the function attached to API Gateway so it can be called from the browser.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  // stuff goes here...
};
```

The problem is that this function never actually fires unless I add the following to the Lambda script:

```
var call = exports.handler();
```

If I do this, however, the `event` argument gets lost.

My handler in the Lambda function code setup is `index.handler`.

Any ideas on what to do to make sure the function fires?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense in that you're manually invoking the handler yourself. You shouldn't need to invoke the handler yourself if you have wired everything up correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @arete - I thought I had things wired up properly.

Comment: No problem, don't forget that you can test invoking the code from within apigateway. See these docs for more information. It will help you iterate faster: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-test-method.html.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js file, try declaring it like
`exports.handler = function index (event, context, callback) {
// stuff goes here...
}`

You should be able to access event and other parameters.